# What is the English phrases for "to bet/vote on a winning candidate"?

Tags: phrases

For example, betting Manchester United rather than a newly-promoted club.
This is not limited to sport and not limited to only two participants.

I've heard it's "to ride on a winning horse", is that correct?
But when I googled it, there's no such thing of it.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

"Back the right horse" might be the expression you're looking for.

> [He backed the right horse with Mr. Koch.](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/07/31/nyregion/public-lives-a-diviner-of-meaning-in-political-names-and-lists.html)
>
> [Of course, every investor wants to back the right horse -- but which assets to choose?](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/07/31/nyregion/public-lives-a-diviner-of-meaning-in-political-names-and-lists.html)
>
> [Everyone wanted to back yhe right horse](http://hbr.org/2005/01/into-the-fray/ar/1)

Also, consider "[a cinch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cinch)" and "a [shoo-in](http://thesaurus.com/browse/cinch)."

> **cinch**: a person or thing certain to fulfill an expectation.
>
> **shoo-in**: a person or thing that is certain to win or succeed.

The Giants are a cinch to win Sunday's game.

[Fineman: Sotomayor is a shoo-in.](http://www.newsweek.com/fineman-sotomayor-shoo-81667)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any authoritative tome to back me on this so what I'm going to say is just based on x decades of use of the language.
I haven't heard the expression "to ride on a winning horse" though it could easily be a regional colloquialism somewhere. However I don't believe that it applies here anyway, nor would the similar "backing a winner". The principal reason is that although in a match between the two clubs Man United is more ***likely*** to win, an upset is not beyond the bounds of possibility. In which case you may have backed Man United, but would not have backed the winner.

Consequently I would think that the betting expression "to back the favourite" (that is, the horse / team / whatever that is ***expected*** to win by the majority of people who are wagering and which consequently has the shortest odds) would be close to what you're looking for.

This presupposes that the expression that you're looking for is one that you use before the fact (when the winner is expected but unknown, as per your example) rather than after the fact (as an expression to describe having backed the actual winner).

Comment: "This presupposes that the expression that you're looking for is one that you use before the fact (when the winner is expected but unknown, as per your example) rather than after the fact (as an expression to describe having backed the actual winner)." --- Yes, this is what I actually meant. That is, to bet/vote a candidate who will most likely win. Also, it's not limited to betting/gambling.

Comment: It doesn't need to be; I've heard (and have used) the expression "backing the favourite" in a metaphorical sense as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Dead cert** is a common way to say 'I'm sure they are guaranteed to win' *(even if it's not true)*

> I'm betting everything on Man. U., they are a dead cert